# Minimization Proof of Conditioning on Gaussian is Gaussian

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, expectation, least-squares

It is well known that $E[X|X+Y]$ is Gaussian if both $X$ and $Y$ are, and the result can be derived using standard density arguments.  However, how can one prove it by only resulting to optimization arguments in order to argue that
$$
\min_{Z \in L^2(\sigma(X+Y))}E[(Z-X)^2] = \min_{Z \in N}E[(Z-X)^2],
$$
where $N$ is the affine subspace of $L^2(\sigma(X+Y))$, spanned by Gaussian random-variables?

**Intuition/Sketch:**
Here is what my trail of thought goes like:

- Since the space of Gaussian random-variables is closed under addition, scalar action, a linear subspace of $L^2(X+Y)$. Moreover, since the limit of a sequence of Gaussians in Gaussian, then $N$ is a closed linear subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2(X+Y)$.
- Therefore, the projection
  $$
  P_N:x \mapsto \operatorname{argmin}_{w \in N}E[(w-x)]^2,
  $$
  is well-defined and single-valued.
- Therefore $L^2(X+Y)\cong N \oplus N^{\perp}$, withthe projection on to the first coordinate, given $P_N$,
- The Triangle-inequality then implies that if $Z \in L^2(X+Y)$, then it's first two moments are well-defined and
  $$
  E[(Z-X)^2]\leq E[(P_N(Z)-X)^2] + E[(P_{N^{\perp}}(Z))^2]
  ,
  $$
  with equality holding if and only if $Z \in N$.
- Hence, if $X$ is Gaussian, then so must the minimzer of $E[(\cdot-X)^2]$ be.

However, this argument doesn't really use the properties of $N$, so it feels like something is missing...

Comment: Updated, the trail of thought.... hopefully the proof sketch is clearer :)

Comment: That $E(X|Y)$ is Gaussian for a Gaussian $n+m$-dimensional vector $(X,Y)$ follows from the fact that uncorrelated components of $(X,Y)$ are independent -- no need to calculate densities. And I don't believe that sums of Gaussian distributed random variables are Gaussian (you need that the joint distribution is Gaussian).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your argument,but I do think there is a simple symmetry based argument that avoids hacking around with densities.  This just generalizes the simple observation that if X,Y i.i.d then E(X|Z = X+Y) = Z/2.  When the correlation between X and Z  is of form  say,$\sqrt{ p/(p+q)}$, then they can be represented as $Z = X_1 + ... + X_p + Y_1 + ....  + Y_q$ where the X_i and Y_j are all i.i.d. Gaussian and $X=   \frac {X_1 + ... + X_p} {\sqrt p}$.
In this case by symmetry all E(X_i|Z) and E(Y_j| Z) are the same and therefore $E(X |Z) \frac p {p+q} Z$.   If necessary, you can perturb slightly to achieve that condition and do a simple limiting argument.

Comment: Interesting argument, but i really do need to work with the minimization formulation, unfortunately.

Comment: @AIM_BLB  And you need to work with the minimization formulation because it is a school assignment?

Comment: No trying to generalize th mechanism...im down school ;)